# Refreshing the data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I need a suggestion on the following problem.
I am working on a .net application with knockout framework.
I have a Javascript file a.js which will call a function from a thirdparty Javascript file googlemapsapi.js 
file which will actually display some markers on the screen.

In my file a.js I have the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    setTimeOut(function( 
        DisplayMarkers(latandlang,callback),5000)
    )}
};
```

The problem is, the marker positions are different 50 times such that 50 different images have to be rendered on the screen but here the 
thirdparty function for the firsttime is only getting executed. Other data is not refreshing.

I placed an alertbox in `thirdParty()` in thirdParty.js also, although the loop gets executed fifty times, the data is not refreshing on the screen.
I am guessing the first time loop data is cached.

Is there any wayout or solution for this?

Edit :
The thirdparty file is googlemapsapi.js

The function is :

```
DisplayMarkers(inputlatandlang,callBack)
{
  map = new google.maps.Map();
  //draw markers
}
```

Comment: What is `thirdParty` function? please add a Jsfiddle or add more script.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code. Try to write it like this:

```
for(i=0; i<50; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    thirdParty(callback)
  }, 5000);
}
```

And remember that `setTimeout` function has no uppercase o.

Comment: Syntax wise there is no problem . Its just a blue print what I gave , the code is executing.